# Which of the following implies $x = y = z$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question:

Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be positive real numbers.  Which of the following implies $x=y=z$?

(1) $x^3+y^3+z^3=3xyz$

(2) $x^3+y^2z+yz^2=3xyz$

(3) $x^3+y^2z+z^2x=3xyz$

(4) $(x+y+z)^3=27xyz$

The answer says that Option (3) is the only one that doesn't satisfy the condition of $x=y=z$.

How? If I put $x=y=z=1$ for each of the options, it is satisfied. Then how does the answer say that Option 3 is incorrect?

Comment: To have an implication you would need that every time you pick $x,y,z$ satisfying (3) it must happen that $x=y=z$. If one takes $x=y=0$ and $z\neq0$ then (3) is satisfied, but not $x=y=z$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Could you explain why you took $y = -z$?

Comment: Note that $y = 2x, z = x$ satisfies $(3)$

Comment: @Cesareo why would I take $y = 2x$? How do you get that intuition?

Comment: Because it is an homogeneous equation. Take $y = \lambda x, z = \mu x$ and then conclude about $\lambda, \mu$

Comment: So do I just put $y = \lambda x$ and $z = \alpha x$ and then solve for $\lambda, \alpha$? How do you get 2,1 respectively?

Comment: Did you try to solve for $\lambda, \mu$ ? Show your efforts.

Comment: @Cesareo i got $1+\lambda + \mu = 3\lambda \mu$ from here i just substitute values i suppose?

Comment: $1+\lambda^2\mu+\mu^2=3\lambda\mu$

Comment: @Cesareo yes , i missed terms while typing from mobile. Then i just sub in some values and solve like a diophantine equation ?

Comment: I think you are missing some conditions.  Are $x$, $y$, and $z$ required to be positive?  There are counterexamples for every option.  For example $(x,y,z)=(1,0,-1)$ invalidates (1) and (4).  Plus, $(x,y,z)=(0,1,0)$ invalidates (2) and (3).  However, if $x,y,z>0$ is true, then each of the options (1), (2), and (4) does imply $x=y=z$.

Comment: @Techie5879  Then, please do not omit conditions.  People cannot read your mind.

Comment: My hint is the AM-GM inequality.  Now as $x,y,z>0$, the given counterexamples do not work anymore.  I am not going to provide you a new counterexample for (3), since I hope Bor Kari will come up with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Making $y = \lambda x, z = \mu x$ and substituting into $(3)$ we get

$$
1+\lambda^2\mu +\mu^2 = 3\lambda\mu
$$

now solving for $\mu$ we get

$$
\mu =\frac 12\left(\lambda(3-\lambda)\pm\sqrt{(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)(\lambda^2-3\lambda-3)}\right) 
$$

imposing now that $\mu$ is real and unique gives us

$$
\lambda = \{1, 2, \frac 12(3\pm \sqrt {17})\}
$$

etc.

Comment: Interesting. Still try to digest. Why is $\mu$ unique?

Comment: To have concrete and immediate results.